# Excluir elementos entregados en una cadena

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tengo una tabla llamada [aux].[LoadCDStockPushSimulation] de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además tengo otra tabla que tengo la información de Sku,Store llamada LastStock2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es obtener todas las combinaciones (Una combinación es Sku,Store) excepto las que tienen locales especificados en la columna Stores.

He intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT s.SKU
            ,ls.Store Store
FROM aux.[LoadCDStockPushSimulation] S
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT NAME Store FROM dbo.SplitString(s.Stores)
)a
INNER JOIN series.LastStock2 ls ON s.SKU = ls.SKU AND (a.Store = ls.Store)
WHERE ProcessId = @ProccessId AND GestionInventario <> 0
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
```

Pero lo que hace esta query es traerme las combinaciones excluidas en vez de las combinaciones no excluidas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pueden ayudar porfavor.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea demasiado tarde para responder, pero por lo que entiendo, se puede obtener mediante la instrucción EXCEPT.

```
SELECT ls.SKU
    ,ls.Store
FROM series.LastStock2 ls 
EXCEPT
SELECT s.SKU 
    ,a.NAME AS Store 
FROM aux.[LoadCDStockPushSimulation] S
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(s.Stores)a
--No supe a donde pertenecian las columnas del WHERE, así que las dejé aquí.
WHERE ProcessId = @ProccessId 
AND GestionInventario <> 0
ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC;
```